# How to know which command button has been clicked in a form

Tags: html, asp-classic

I have a form which has 3 command buttons. I want to know which command button has been clicked and store the value in a session variable
how to do it.

I am getting empty value in the session variable

```
<form method="post" name = "theform" >
  <table>
    <tr>
         <td align="left" width="100%">
             <input type="submit" name = "button" id ="idbutton1" value="Value1">      
              </td>
         <td align="left" width="100%">
             <input type="submit" name = "button" id ="idbutton2" value="Value2">
              </td>

        <td align="left" width="100%">
             <input type="submit" name = "button" id ="idbutton3" value="Value3">
              </td>
       </tr>
</table>
</form>

Session("type")=Request.Form("button")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that `Request.Form("button")` contains a value before assigning it to the session variable, otherwise you will be assigning an empty string value to `Session("type")` every time the page loads.

```
if request.form("button") <> "" then Session("type") = Request.Form("button")
```

Comment: Can you update your post with your ASP code please? You also need to explain in more detail what you're trying to do. Are you just wanting to store the clicked button value as a session, or are you trying to get the ID value? Because that isn't posted in the form data.

Comment: I wanted to store the clicked button value in a session variable, On the basis  of this session value i need to perform different work/action in the nextpage .Hence trying to figure it out how to get the button values. Like each button will redirect to same page but if I can get the button value i got to know which button is clicked and I can do some work according to that button value.

Comment: <input type="submit" name = "button" id ="idbutton1" value="Value1" onclick="location.href='abc.asp'">                                                                                                
<input type="submit" name = "button" id ="idbutton2" value="Value2" onclick="location.href='abc.asp'">                                                                                                
<input type="submit" name = "button" id ="idbutton3" value="Value3" onclick="location.href='abc.asp'">

Comment: Your onclick event will prevent the form from being posted. Do the redirect in your asp after assigning the session value: `Dim button_val : button_val = request.form("button") : if button_val <> "" then Session("type") = button_val  : response.redirect("abc.asp")`

Answer (score 0):

you can use this jquery to identify which button you clicked and what is the value of that button :

```
$( "#idbutton1" ).click(function() {
alert( $("#idbutton1").val() );
});


$( "#idbutton2" ).click(function() {
 alert( $("#idbutton2").val() );
});

...
```

and instead of alert you can save it in your session.

*but this method is not dynamic and not good enough for too many buttons

**edited :general mode:**

you can get the id and value like this in general:

```
$( "input[name=button]" ).click(function() {
 alert( $(this).attr("id") );
 alert($(this).val());
 button_value = $(this).val();
});
```

and if you use c# or Django or anything in your backend you can send the variable to it with ajax and then save it to your session :

.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: '/yourfunction',
        data: {'button_value':button_value},
        dataType: 'json',

```
    success: function (data) {
    // do anything
    }
  )}
```

and you can get the variable in your function and save it in Session.

Comment: The value of the clicked button will be posted in the form data, so jQuery isn't necessary. If he's wanting to know the ID value then javascript might be the way to go, but I'm not sure that's what he's asking.